# Does updating a nonclustered index sometimes register a SEEK in dm_db_index_usage_stats?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

We have a poorly designed index on an uniqueidentifier. We cannot find any queries on our system that would have cause to use it, but that doesn't mean connecting applications definitely don't need it.

The table has in excess of 600 million rows with a clustered index that is not unique. Each clustered index value is duplicated over 1 million times. Due to the size of the table, we are nervous to delete an index because it is very difficult to recreate it. No keys.

There are no scans or lookups against it in dm_db_index_usage_stats, but dm_db_index_usage_stats does show a small number of seeks against it.

We have searched the query plans and only found times where it has been referenced as part of a larger clustered index update; no explicit index seeks.

Could they have been done as part of a statistics update, part of the index update, or is it possible that the query engine uses it on deeper self-joining calculations , because it is the only unique field in the table?

If someone can explain the seeks, we might be able to drop it and get a performance boost.

Comment: There is no way somebody on this side of the internet can possibly answer that accurately. It isn't even clear if the index is used or not. In one sentence you state there are seeks in index usage, but then in the next sentence there aren't.

Comment: "it is the only unique field in the table", so what are the keys, and is there a clustered index?

Comment: If the index is being minimally used, regardless if it's a seek or scan, *and* you see performance issues with inserts / updates / deletes then why not consider dropping it anyways?

Comment: @SeanLange I said there were seeks in dm_db_index_usage_stats but no explicit index seeks in the plans. I want to know if seeks in dm_db_index_usage_stats mean queries are using it, or are index/stats updates or something else registering seeks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft scsimon - I have updated: 'The table has in excess of 600 million rows with a clustered index that is not unique. Each clustered index value is duplicated over 1 million times. Due to the size of the table, we are nervous to delete an index because it is very difficult to recreate it. No keys.'

Comment: Why do you think you'll get a "performance boost" by dropping the only key on this table?  If it's because of insert performance, can you generate the values with NEWSEQUENTIALID instead?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Each week, we insert 2 million records. An index on a uniqueidentifier is always fragmenting. Inserts would be quicker if it was removed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The insert is in one go, taking up to 10 hrs. We believe that statistics updates are struggling, so we are removing unused indexes.

Comment: Yeah, i'd suspect dropping the index would help tremendously with that large of an insert. Also, since your uniqueidentifier is a surrogate key, without a being a key, there is no real need for it. If it was the PK and you were upserting then i'd understand, but I don't see it's purpose based on what you have told us, thus can't see a use for the index.

Comment: So can the DM table register seeks when there aren’t any queries using the index?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the guid inserted is generated elsewhere, so cannot be sequential.

Comment: You technically can generate sequential GUIDs outside SQL Server, but it's obviously harder.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2012/07/03/how-to-generate-sequential-guids-for-sql-server-in-net/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks, but we have too many systems to update and the problem of an insert that increases in time week by week. If I can put the seeks down to system routines, I’ll delete it. That’s what I want to  explain in theory.

Comment: "600 million rows with a clustered index that is not unique" - I suppose you're in OLAP not OLTP? If so, what kind of performance you hope to get when dropping this index?

Comment: @serge This is a legacy system that we cannot change without serious planning and risk assessment. It is accessed and updated like a live table but the data and its use is also similar to that of a warehouse table. Dropping the index will increase the speed of inserts. The guid is created in many other applications, so swapping to a sequential guid is not possible application changes.

Comment: Can you create a test copy of your database and delete the index in the test database to see what happens?

Comment: @Khal_Drogo We have test copies and deleting it does improve the particular INSERT routine, but the test db won't be connected to all the processes and possibility that that index is required by something somewhere that we have forgotten about. We want to know if the small number of seeks could be caused by something other than an explicit clause/join on that GUID column.

Comment: @cloudsafe ok, it's OLAP (DW). Are you really perturbed the performance of existing insertions in the fact table? If so, did you insert the rows in 1/ bulk insert mode, 2/ batch mode by N in transaction or 3/ one by one?

Comment: @Serge changing changing transaction logging methods and batch sizes has not helped.

Comment: @cloudsafe what do you mean? `begin tran; insert1; insert2;..;inset10 commit;` is usually about 10 times faster that 10 sequential inserts. Bulk insert is so much faster.

Comment: @Serge Without indexes it is very quick. With indexes, it has to update them, taking the time.

Comment: @cloudsafe I'm aware that INSERT is faster without indexes. However, recreating indexes for just add rows to DW fact table is not a good practice when % of inserting rows is relatively small (i.e. < 5). So my question about bothering index was in this scenario.

Comment: @cloudsafe so I'd propose to check index usage in the following way: add new data, recreate indexes and statistics manually (automatic stats -> off), clear index stats and monitor the usage until the next data arrived.

Comment: @serge It is not a DW table. It is a live, continually updated and vital part of the system, but also has DW properties. It was a badly designed system. We are confident in managing what we have, just want to know if the small number of SEEKS on the GUID column are explicit or requested as part of something behind-the-scenes. We don't want any surprises when it is removed on LIVE.

Comment: @cloudsafe so remove it in pre-prod or even in "bench" or "qual" not in prod, what's the problem?

Comment: @serge It is removed from our testing db, but testing db is not connected and cannot be connected to any of the myriad applications that connect to LIVE and affect LIVE data.

Comment: @cloudsafe If you drop it, the table still have its primary key?

Comment: @serge there is no PK. The GUID index is the only unique index.

Comment: @cloudsafe ok I see this sometimes in fact tables. So this index may be used in some internals of SELECT to identify the rows. I'd like suggest to make this index a non-clustered PK but do not to drop it. The table without PK has some flaws.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server indexes are essentially copies of the data that already exist in the table, ordered and filtered in different ways to improve the performance of executed queries. Seeks, scans and lookups operators are used to access SQL Server indexes.

**Seeks operators** – the Seek operator uses the ability of SQL Server to search indexes to get rows from a clustered or nonclustered indexes, and the seek can be a physical as well as a logical operator. The index seeks only deals with qualified rows and with pages that comprises those qualified rows, and therefore the cost of the seek is less expensive. In simple words, seeks to retrieve just selected rows from the table.

**Scans operators** – the Scans operator scans the clustered index, and it is designed to deal with every row in the scanned table regardless of whether the row is qualified or not. A scan operator can be effective for small tables or in a situation where most of the rows are qualified. In simple terms, scans retrieve all the rows from the table.

**Lookups operators** – the lookup operator, is used for retrieving the non-key data from the results set retrieved from the nonclustered index. After the rows are retrieved from the nonclustered index, lookups are used for retrieving column information from these rows.

While proper use of SQL Server indexes can grant improved performance of executed queries and thus the SQL Server in general, setting them up improperly or not setting them where needed, can have the significantly degraded the performance of the executed queries. Moreover, having unnecessary indexes that are not used by queries can be problematic as well.

SQL Server indexes are an excellent tool for improving the performance of SELECT queries, but at the same time, SQL Server indexes have negative effects on data updates. INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations cause index updating and thus duplicating the data that already exists in the table. As a result, this increases the duration of transactions and the query execution and often can result in locking, blocking, deadlocking and quite frequent execution timeouts. For large databases or tables, the storage space is also affected by redundant indexes. A critical goal, of any SQL Server DBA, is to maintain indexes including creating required indexes but at the same time removing the ones that are not used.

**Finding unused indexes**

SQL Server provides a significant amount of index information via Dynamic Management Views (DMVs). The dm_db_index_usage_stats DMV displays essential information about index usage, and it can be a useful tool in identifying unused SQL Server indexes. When an index is used for the first time, a new row gets created in the `dm_db_index_usage_stats` DMV and subsequently updated every time an index is used. However, as with every DMV, the data present in dm_db_index_usage_stats contain only the data since the last SQL Server service restart (SQL Server service restart resets the data in the DMV). Therefore, it is critical that there is a sufficient time since the last SQL Server restart that allows correctly determining which indexes are good candidates to be dropped.

A simple query that can be used to get the list of unused indexes in SQL Server (updated indexes not used in any seeks, scan or lookup operations) is as follows:

```
SELECT
    objects.name AS Table_name,
    indexes.name AS Index_name,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates
FROM
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    INNER JOIN sys.objects ON dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = objects.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes ON indexes.index_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id AND dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = indexes.OBJECT_ID
WHERE
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_lookups = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans = 0
ORDER BY
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates DESC
```

The above query returns all unused indexes of all types. This query can frequently be found on the internet but isn’t an ideal/complete option. By using such a query to find and clean unused indexes may lead to unexpected behavior because this query does not take into account primary key and unique key constraints when collecting the unused index data. Both, primary and unique key constraints indexes could be “unused,” but deleting those indexes could be problematic. To prevent that scenario, the query above must be refined by adding two lines of code after the WHERE to exclude the primary and unique keys from being listed as unused and potentially deleted.

```
SELECT
    objects.name AS Table_name,
    indexes.name AS Index_name,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates
FROM
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    INNER JOIN sys.objects ON dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = objects.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes ON indexes.index_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id AND dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = indexes.OBJECT_ID
WHERE
    indexes.is_primary_key = 0 -- This condition excludes primary key constarint
    AND
    indexes. is_unique = 0 -- This condition excludes unique key constarint
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats. user_lookups = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans = 0
ORDER BY
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates DESC
```

The above query lists all unused queries that are not primary and unique keys, but it also lists all unused indexes that SQL Server has not worked with. The user_updates column in the dm_db_index_usage_stats DMV is counting where the index was updated as the application has carried some changes to data, so the index was updated. To do that the `dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates <> 0` conditions should be added to the previous script.

```
SELECT
    objects.name AS Table_name,
    indexes.name AS Index_name,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates
FROM
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    INNER JOIN sys.objects ON dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = objects.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes ON indexes.index_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id AND dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = indexes.OBJECT_ID
WHERE
    indexes.is_primary_key = 0 --This line excludes primary key constarint
    AND
    indexes. is_unique = 0 --This line excludes unique key constarint
    AND 
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates <> 0 -- This line excludes indexes SQL Server hasn’t done any work with
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats. user_lookups = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans = 0
ORDER BY
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates DESC
```

So now that unused SQL Server indexes are identified and listed, it can be determined which indexes can be dropped safely, but again that has to be done very carefully.

Comment: We already employ procedures to find unused indexes, but we have seeks against an index we should never be using and would have no call to use. I am asking if seeks can be registered by statistics operations or unique key logistics; whether seeks do not have to be registered by explicitly searching for a column value by a statement.

Comment: So, I'm not getting you clearly. Could you please enlighten me clearly, Whether do you want to seek without indexes?

Comment: @kousik I want to know if the seeks registered in the DM table were down to something other than an explicit query statement.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 brings clustered [columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/using-clustered-columnstore-indexes?view=sql-server-2014), and they’re totally writeable – you can insert, update, or delete into them. They’re best suited for wide data warehouse fact tables that have lots of columns, but your queries might only want a few of those columns, and they might pick any of the columns for filtering. These types of tables are notoriously difficult to index, and columnstore indexes can give you dramatic performance improvements here.

Comment: Books Online says you’d better be sure your access patterns all benefit from columnstore indexes, because you can’t add any nonclustered indexes to your columnstore tables